# Can't use touchesBegan because of delegate from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, touch

I instantiated a class, set the delegate and calls a method then I try to use the method touchesBegan but doesn't work, when I remove the code that instantiate the touchesBegan works, can help me how to use the both together?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

   _partyDAO = [PartyDAO alloc];
   _partyDAO.delegate = self;
   [_partyDAO getHot];

}
```

Comment: *"try to use the method touchesBegan but doesn't work"* - what does "try to use" mean and what does "doesn't work" refer to?

Answer (score 0):

What is partyDAO? Try

```
_partyDAO = [PartyDAO alloc] init];
```